end of string not working with regexp_matches() in PostgreSQL
I have a table in a PostgreSQL DB and I am trying to extract a substring with a certain pattern from a string as a result of extracting specific data from a jsonb column. The string of interest is extracted by using the following command (I include all the details in case of some side-effect that I didn't notice):
SELECT (e.content #> '{RefOrder, Ordertxt}')::text
FROM cistec.kis_t_event e
WHERE kat::text = 'MEDI'::text
AND (sender='NEO_FK' OR sender='PAED_IPS') AND dat >= '2023-01-01' AND dat <= '2023-12-31' AND LEFT(patnr, 1) <> 'T'
AND patnr NOT IN ('381227', '381234', '381235', '225328') AND fkey NOT ILIKE '%IF%'

The problem is that I want to extract a substring with a certain pattern using a regular expression, but I don't obtain the same result in two cases that for me they should be equivalent (obviously they are not and I need to understand why):
Case 1: In the first case, I pick one particular value from one of the records as result of the above query.
SELECT (regexp_matches('1. Res. Fieber, Schmerz: max. 1 Stk  max. 4x/24h, min. Intervall 6h rektal; 20- (25) mg/kg/Dosis; NG 10-15mg/kg/Dosis; max. 4x/d; 20 mg/kg', '(\d+(\.\d+)?\s?(g|mg|ucg|mmol)\/kg\w*(\/(h|d))?)$'))[1]

Result: 20 mg/kg as it should be.
Case 2: In the second case, I apply the following CTE to the concerning table from the DB.
SELECT
    (e.content #> '{RefOrder, Ordertxt}')::text,
    (regexp_matches((e.content #> '{RefOrder, Ordertxt}')::text, '(\d+(\.\d+)?\s?(g|mg|ucg|mmol)\/kg\w*(\/(h|d))?)$'))[1]
FROM cistec.kis_t_event e
WHERE kat::text = 'MEDI'::text
AND (sender='NEO_FK' OR sender='PAED_IPS') AND dat >= '2023-01-01' AND dat <= '2023-12-31' AND LEFT(patnr, 1) <> 'T'
AND patnr NOT IN ('381227', '381234', '381235', '225328') AND fkey NOT ILIKE '%IF%'

Result: empty.
But even weirder: if I remove the dollar sign ($) to the regex I obtain the expected result in the corresponding line:
SELECT
    (e.content #> '{RefOrder, Ordertxt}')::text,
    (regexp_matches((e.content #> '{RefOrder, Ordertxt}')::text, '(\d+(\.\d+)?\s?(g|mg|ucg|mmol)\/kg\w*(\/(h|d))?)'))[1]
FROM cistec.kis_t_event e
WHERE kat::text = 'MEDI'::text
AND (sender='NEO_FK' OR sender='PAED_IPS') AND dat >= '2023-01-01' AND dat <= '2023-12-31' AND LEFT(patnr, 1) <> 'T'
AND patnr NOT IN ('381227', '381234', '381235', '225328') AND fkey NOT ILIKE '%IF%'

Result: 15mg/kg.
But the problem is that I want to obtain the substring when it is the last part of the string (so 20 mg/kg not 15mg/kg. Hence, the use of $ to capture that feature.
Do you know why this behavior?

Try adding an optional CR: (\d+(?:\.\d+)?\s?(?:g|mg|ucg|mmol)/kg\w*(?:/[hd])?)\r?$

It would help if you could add a sample table since there could be something wrong with the strings in the table, e.g., a space last. This would then match without the $ but not with the $.

If there are any non-word chars possible there use (\d+(?:\.\d+)?\s?(?:g|mg|ucg|mmol)/kg\w*(?:/[hd])?)\W*$

@MatsKindahl: There is no space at the end of the string. The string that I took in the Case 1 was copy + paste of the value of the jsonb column from one row of the table.

@Eden Did the response below help?

Yes. I understood that the rules of SO forbid to say: "thank you, it works!"

@eden Yup, but you can accept the answer as a answering your question (there is a checkmark you can click). :)

The problem is that the #> operator returns the value of the field "raw", that is, with quotes if it is a string and without quotes if it is some other value.
For example, with the following table and contents:
create table sample (metric_id serial, content jsonb);

insert into sample(content) values
       ('{"one": "first content"}'),
       ('{"two": "second magic"}'),
       ('{"three": "whatever"}'),
       ('{"four": "oops"}');

You get this value:
mats=# select metric_id, content #> '{one}' from sample;
 metric_id |    ?column?     
-----------+-----------------
         1 | "first content"
         2 | 
         3 | 
         4 | 
(4 rows)

As a result, the regular expression will not be able to match the end of the string:
mats=# select metric_id, content #> '{one}', regexp_matches((content #> '{one}')::text, 'content$') from sample;
 metric_id | ?column? | regexp_matches 
-----------+----------+----------------
(0 rows)

If you add the quote to the regular expression, it will match it:
mats=# select metric_id,
mats-#        content #> '{one}',
mats-#        regexp_matches(content #> '{one}', 'content$') from '{one}')::text, 'content"$') from sample;
 metric_id |    ?column?     | regexp_matches 
-----------+-----------------+----------------
         1 | "first content" | {"content\""}
(1 row)

But more sensible is to use the #>> operator to extract it as text and match that directly:
mats=# select metric_id,
mats-#        content #>> '{one}',
mats-#        regexp_matches(content #>> '{one}', 'content$') from sample;
 metric_id |   ?column?    | regexp_matches 
-----------+---------------+----------------
         1 | first content | {content}
(1 row)

